# Dojo find a node under a node

Tags: javascript, dojo

If we have node2 under node1 so then node1 has child node2 and many other children

The way dojo find node2 from node1, is

```
var node2 = dojo.query(node1).query(node2);
```

correct?

Actually I am looking for "script" element under and "input", don't know the best way to get it from Dojo. Sorry I am very newbie on Dojo.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code?  Both my answer and @BuffaloBuffalo's give you options, but it really depends on your specific case.

Comment: @Craig Swing Thank you. You both give excellent answer hope SO give option can check on multiple answers to close. Here I have reference to the node so BuffaloBuffalo serve the need. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want to provide is the second, optional parameter to `dojo/query`, the root node.

```
var listOfMatchingNodes = dojo.query(/* css selectors */,node1);
```

As noted in the [reference guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.8/dojo/query.html), the second parameter will limit the query to results that are children of the given node.

Answer (score 2):

What @BuffaloBuffalo posted is one potential way to do it if you have a reference to the parent node.  If you don't have a reference to the parent node, the following might work for you.

```
<div class="parent">
    <div>Find ME!!!</div>
</div>

require(["dojo/query", "dojo/NodeList-dom"], function(query) {
    query(".parent > div").forEach(function(node) {
        // do something with the node
    });
});
```

Regardless the link @BuffaloBuffalo posted should help you find the answer for your situation.

Comment: Thank you, does this solution doable for version 1.6?

Comment: ".parent > div" should work for 1.6.  http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.6/dojo/query.html

Comment: Thank you, hands up to the great support